# delete directories in hdfs based on the value passed

Tags: linux, bash, hdfs

I have some directories like below in `HDFS`.

```
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-07/seq=1
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-07/seq=2
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-08/seq=1
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-08/seq=2
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-09/seq=1
```

I am trying to delete the directories where date_loaded <= '2020-07-08'

I did like below

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-07
hdfs dfs -rm -R user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-08
```

As you see I used to `hdfs` cli statements to achieve what I want.

I would like to delete the directories in a single shot using command or script based on the date_loaded value I pass.

For example.

If I pass the `date_loaded` value as `2020-07-08` to the script then the below directories should be deleted

```
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-07/seq=1
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-07/seq=2
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-08/seq=1
/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=2020-07-08/seq=2
```

How can i achieve what I want

Comment: It's not clear why 2020-07-07s should also be deleted. Did you want to always get the "day-before" as well? Else write a function for this and add it to your `.bashrc` or other `.` file. `hdfs-rm () { hdfs dfs -rm -R user/$USER/test/date_loaded=$1 ; }`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=/user/$USER/test/date_loaded=
cutoffdate=2020-07-08

declare -A to_be_removed
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in "$prefix"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/; do
    [[ ${dir#"$prefix"} > $cutoffdate/ ]] && break
    to_be_removed[$dir]=1
done

echo rm -rf -- "${!to_be_removed[@]}"
```

The variable `USER` must be set before use. Remove the `echo` and replace the `rm` command with yours after making sure it will work as intended.

Comment: I am getting only `rm -rf --` as output

Comment: @nmr What's output of `echo "/user/$USER/test/date_loaded="*` ?

Comment: `/user/myusername/test/date_loaded=`

Comment: @nmr then no pathname exists in your directory tree beginning with `/user/myusername/test/date_loaded=`. In other words, there are no directories to be removed. So the output you get is expected in this case.